# How to manage the iptables for many servers?

Tags: iptables

I am new to manage linux server.

We have many dedicated server in different regions. 
Some of them serve mysql and allow access each other.

I can modify iptables configuration to add rule accepting port 3306 requests 
from some server in iptables by myself. 
Is there other way to manage many iptables efficiently ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Firewall builder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/) or you can also use [puppet iptables module](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-iptables).

***Firewall Builder supports GUI based firewall policy configuration and management on the following firewalls***:

- Linux iptables - 2.4 & 2.6 kernels
- Cisco router access control lists (ACL)
- Cisco ASA/PIX
- Cisco Firewall Service Module (FWSM)
- OpenBSD pf
- FreeBSD ipfw and ipfilter
- HP ProCurve ACL

Answer (score 3):

Use puppet chef or cfengine to distribiute rules and restart iptables.

Answer (score 2):

I use Shorewall and Shorewall-lite.  On the master server I have the following arrangement:

- /etc/shorewall - firewall configuration for the server
- /etc/shorewall/common - common files such as standard zone definitions, policies, macros, etc.
- /etc/shorewall/hostname - definition for each host.

Using the common directory allows me to avoid repeating definitions for each server.  The config file has a path variable which can be used to specify a list of directories containing common files.  If you have a lot of servers with the same rule set you could place the rules in the `common` directory, or a different shared directory for that class of servers.

I use `make` to build the firewall scripts `firewall` and `firewall.conf`.  These are then distributed and executed using `ssh`.

I've tried some of the graphical firewall builders, but find shorewall with its config files easier to work with and verify.  I keep the whole configuration directory in `git` to allow me to easily verify changes before implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For chef on Ubuntu you can use the [UFW cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/ufw).

Beware: UFW doesn't work on Open VZ without [many modifications](http://www.lokkju.com/blog/archives/150).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem of remotely administering iptables on many servers. Since no satisfying solution existed we developed [rfw](https://github.com/securitykiss-com/rfw)

With rfw (remote firewall) you can add and delete iptables rules on many servers from a single point of control using any HTTP client via REST API.

See the [rfw tutorial](http://www.securitykiss.com/resources/tutorials/rfw_project/)

The project is open source and released under MIT License.